# Implement Delegate at Run Time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have a universal view controller class which all of the view controller classes in my app inherit from which has the following `loadView` method:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    if (viewType == UIStandardViewControllerViewTypeUIView)
    {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        [self setView: view];
        [view release];
    }
    else if (viewType == UIStandardViewControllerViewTypeUIScrollView)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        [self setView: scrollView];
        [scrollView release];
    }
    else if (viewType == UIStandardViewControllerViewTypeUITableViewPlain || viewType == UIStandardViewControllerViewTypeUITableViewGrouped)
    {
        UITableViewStyle tableViewStyle; 

        if (viewType == UIStandardViewControllerViewTypeUITableViewPlain)
        {
            tableViewStyle = UITableViewStylePlain;
        }
        else 
        {
            tableViewStyle = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
        }

        UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style: tableViewStyle];
        [self setView: tableView];
        [tableView release];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
    [backButton release];
}
```

I have it done this way for a lot of reasons that I don't feel like getting into. Anyhow, as you'll notice, one of the view types to implement is a `tableview`. As we all know, a `tableview` needs a `delegate` and a `datasource`. I was wondering if it's possible to implement the `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` at run time when I know a tableView is the choice that was made?

If not, does anyone else have any ideas how I can do this without having to manually implement my delegate and datasource in the inheriting view controller class? If I implement the data source and delegate at compile time (normally) in my `UIStandardViewController` class, then I get warning because I need to implement the mandatory data source and delegate methods in my standard view controller class. Would you implement these and then just override them in child class? Or anyone have any idea of how I can do this cleanly?

UPDATE: Was wondering, if I just implemented the delegate and data source in my UIStandardViewController class, and also implemented empty versions of the required methods, would this be a lot of extra overhead when I didn't use a tableview?

Comment: No it's not possible.
But you might want to rethink your structure, why do you want to do this?

Comment: a) In order to use loadView, you have to be able to initialize a view in it, b) in subclasses off of this, I attach stuff to the view like gesture recognizer and want to do it in loadview properly. I mean why does it matter, ultimately, when you do loadview you're going to implement one of these three as follows anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're asking here, but I think there's a more fundamental problem in your OO design here that should probably be addressed in a different way than what you're asking.

Comment: @dougw the only thing I can think of is to split off a separate subclass of uitableviewcontroller which is what I'm trying to avoid so I don't have to replicate code

Comment: @CoDEFRo - Well one option would be to use multiple levels of inheritance the same way Apple has done it for UITableView.  Another option would be to use internal classes as the delegate & datasources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a controller (just controller, not view controller) that implements data source and the table view delegate. You will only create an instance if needed.

Also note, that you are using the Factory pattern. You should use a class method to create new views. The signature would be something like `+(UIView *)viewWithType:(ViewTypeStyle) viewTypeSyle)`

*TableController.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableController : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

*TableController.m*

```
#import "TableController.h"

@implementation TableController

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) TableController *controller;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView = tableView_;
@synthesize controller = controller_;


-(void)dealloc
{
    self.tableView = nil;
    self.controller= nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.controller = [[[TableController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
    self.tableView.delegate = self.controller;
    self.tableView.dataSource= self.controller;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//...

@end
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that what I was doing was an actual pattern. Why do you recommend a class method to create the views?

Comment: If you add a class method to your view class, you don't need to create an object to create another object. Please note, that you'll find this pattern all over cocoa. Ie `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:number]`

Comment: One more thing to notice: these method should auto release.

Comment: Anyway you can give an example of controller that you're talking about? I want to accept this answer as correct just have no way of verifying the controller thing. Appreciate the help.

Comment: But you are aware of [MVC?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how you can write a controller that's not a viewcontroller?