# How can I subclass a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to subclass a UITableView as I want to create a reusable table view component in my application.

The idea is instead of using a delegate for say cellForRowAtIndexPath I want the table view itself to get that call.

I don't think I want a UITableViewController as this UITableView that I want to build has to live in various UIViewControllers (and these UIViewController might have UITableViews of their own).

I subclassed my UITableView as:

```
@interface ShareUITableView : UITableView
```

but none of its methods get called.

My ShareUITableView is created via the NIB by setting the custom class to ShareUITableView.  I have verified in code that a ShareUITableView is instantiated.

My UITableView does not delegate to its view controller, so that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should still go with a Controller class. I expect subclassing UITableView to be tedious work — if possible with reasonable amount at all.

There is no problem to have UIViewController/NoViewController implemented the delegate and datasource and yet assign another controller to a specific tableView. note, that the datasource and delegate don't need to be subclasses of UITableViewController.

have a look at this answer: [Implement Delegate at Run Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005254/implement-delegate-at-run-time/9005444#9005444)

> My UITableView does not delegate to its view controller, so that's not the problem.

You have to have to use delegate and datasource, that is how TableViews are filled and configured. otherwise you will have to overwrite every method of UITableView — including private ones, a no-go if you want into AppStore. Recreating UITableView without subclassing it would be even easier.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the purpose of a UITableViewController.  I was thinking it was to be used in place of a UIViewController when its primary mission is to own 1 table view.  But I've got a bunch of complex views in different UIViewControllers and I just want to share a type of UITableView, namely my ShareUITableView.  Is this just not in the cards?

Comment: A UITableviewController is just a UIViewController, where the view property has to hold a UITableView. All the fact stuff is done through the delegate and datasource.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005254/implement-delegate-at-run-time/9005444#9005444

Comment: It would solve your problem, if you'd understand, how tableviews are generated and how delegate and datasource are taken in account. You are creating yourself a problem of giant size. when you will understand that please come back and accept this answer.

Comment: i think your answer referred to by your link makes sense, but i'm not sure what that has to do with subclassing a UITableViewController.  pretty convinced I don't want a UITableViewController just the method you outline in the link, right?

Comment: that is just the implementation of the delegate and the datasource. has nothing to do with the UITableViewController.

Comment: no, not chat, I am just leaving my computer. Here it is late at night.

Comment: yes i realize that it has nothing to do with a UITableViewController.  i was saying that your link is a solution to the problem not subclassing a UITableViewController as you say in the first line of your answer above.

Comment: In the end it doesn't matter, if you do it in an UIViewController, or like shown in that link. I will rephrase it

Comment: thanks. and accept some of the answers to your other questions!

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you, you need this class declaration:

```
@interface ShareUITableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource>
```

And then, in your class constructor, you should assign the instance itself as its own datasource:

```
- (id)init
{
    //...
    self.dataSource = self;
    //...
}
```

Of course, the class will have to adopt the protocol.

Good luck!

Comment: That sounds like a good plan, but my init override isn't being called.  As I mentioned it seems like I have a ShareUITableView instance as I can examine that the instance of it in the view controller is of that type (I am setting the custom class in the NIB to ShareUITableView).

Comment: Interface Builder won't call -init. Instead, use -awakeFromNib: or -initWithCoder:

Comment: I think the basis of MVC would frown upon using a tableView class having its own datasource & delegate methods.

Answer (score 6):

MyTableView.h

```
// MyTableView.h

// This overrides the UITableViewDataSource with your own so you can add any methods   you would like.
@protocol MyTableViewDataSource <UITableViewDataSource>

@required
// This is where you put methods that are required for your custom table to work (optional)
- (int)myRequiredMethod;

@optional
// This is where you put methods that are optional, like settings (optional)

@end

// This overrides the UITableViewDelegate with your own so you can add any methods you would like.
@protocol MyTableViewDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>

@required
// This is where you put methods that are required for your custom table to work (optional)

@optional
// This is where you put methods that are optional, like settings (optional)

@end

// Make sure you add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource implementations.
@interface MyTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    // Your customer datasource and delegate.
    id <MyTableViewDataSource> myDataSource;
    id <MyTableViewDelegate> myDelegate;
}

@end
```

MyTableView.m

```
// MyTableView.m

#import "MyTableView.h"

@implementation MyTableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        // This is how you can use your custom method.
        int i = [myDataSource myRequiredMethod];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // This assigns the delegate and datasource you assigned to File's Owner in your xib to your custom methods
    myDataSource = (id<MyTableViewDataSource>)self.dataSource;
    myDelegate = (id<MyTableViewDelegate>)self.delegate;
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
}

// This is an example of how to override an existing UITableView method.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // This calls the method implemented in your ViewController. See Below.
    NSInteger rows = [myDataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    return rows;
}

@end
```

MyViewController.h

```
// MyViewController.h

#import "MyTableView.h"

// Use MyTableViewDataSource and MyTableViewDelegate instead of UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyTableViewDataSource, MyTableViewDelegate> {

@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
// MyViewController.m

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// This method will be overridden by myTableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (int)myRequiredMethod {
    return 2;
}
```

Subclassing is a great way to make reusable custom UI elements.

Comment: When I call [self reloadData] after API request is called and array loaded in MyTableView.m, the data won't shown. How to solve this one?