# Fails to call delegate/datasource methods in UITableView implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have created .h and .m files for `UITableView` called `mainTableViewgm.h` and `mainTableViewgm.m` resp. and I am calling -`initWithFrame`: method from my main view controller to this `mainTableViewgm.m` implementation file

```
[[mainTableViewgm alloc]initWithFrame:tableViewOne.frame]
```

Note that this tableview is in my main view controller. But I have created separate files for the tableView and have also set the custom class to `mainTableViewgm` in storyboard.

the `-initWithFrame:` methods appears as follows

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

//NSLog(@"kource data");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    [self setDelegate:self];
    [self setDataSource:self];
    [self tableView:self cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
    [self tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    // Initialization code
}

return self;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"kource data");
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"kource data2");
UITableViewCell*cellOne =[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
cellOne.detailTextLabel.text=@"text did appear";
return cellOne;
}
```

the `-initWithFrame:` is being called fine along with the 'if (self)' block in this method. But the problem is `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are not being automatically called here . `kource data`/`kource data2` never appear in log. What do I do to load the table? Are the `delegate`/`datasource` being set incorrectly?

I must mention that I have also set the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableviewDataSource` protocols:

```
@interface mainTableViewgm : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take the deceleration of cellforrow and number of sections out of the initwithframe method and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableview is not loaded when the controller is initializing, so you cannot do that in the `init` methods. You have to move your code to the `viewDidLoad` method.

Also you are not setting the delegate and datasource on the tableview object (probably a type, you are setting them on the view controller). It should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self]; // <- This will trigger the tableview to (re)load it's data
}
```

Next thing is to implement the UITableViewDataSource methods correctly. `UITableViewCell *cellOne =[[UITableViewCell alloc] init];` is not returning a valid cell object. You should use at least `initWithStyle:`. And take a look how to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. A typical implementation would look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Reuse/create cell    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Update cell contents
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Your text here";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"text did appear";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned above I want to use the delegate/datasource methods in the UITableView type .m file I have created specially for this table (mainTableViewgm.m) and not the viewController.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that, but subclassing UITableView sounds like a bad idea to me. It might need a lot of more work in order to get everything to work propertly. So why do you need to subclass UITableView? Can't you just control the tableview using it's datasource and delegate?

Comment: Here's another link that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144146/how-can-i-subclass-a-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I've been doing XCode programming for two years, and still hit this issue.

I had the same problem with XCode 6.1 - I was setting my `UITableView`'s delegate & dataSource in the `viewWillAppear` function, but none of the delegate functions were kicking in.

However, if I right-clicked on the `UITableView` on the Storyboard, the circles for delegate and dataSource were empty.

The solution, then, is to hold down the CTRL key, and drag from each of these circles up to the name of your `UIView` which contains your `UITableView`:

[image]

After doing this, my `UITableView` happily populated itself.

(So, we're upto v6.1 of XCode now are we ?  Do you think Apple ever going to make this thing, you know, *friendly*...?  I would quite like to add a Bookmark in my code... that'd be a nice feature.)