# how to display json pattern in tableview

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am new to IOS i need to display *json* fetched data into *uitableview* my json pattern look like this.

```
{"output":[{"id":{"php":"1"},"name":{"php":"ramkumar"},"image":{"1":"http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1432636961.jpg"}},{"id":{"php":"2"},"name":{"php":"rakshi"},"image":{"2":"http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1440371842.jpg"}},{"id":{"android":"1"},"name":{"android":"Vijayan"},"image":{"3":"http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1432636961.jpg"}},{"id":{"android":"2"},"name":{"android":"vishali"},"image":{"4":"http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1440371842.jpg"}},{"id":{"android":"3"},"name":{"android":"Niranjan"},"image":{"5":"http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1432636961.jpg"}}]}
```

*viewdidload* coding:

i created json url into array format in viewdidload itself and displayed successfully in nslog but in tableview it can failed.

```
if(data){
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];


        NSLog(@"%@",json);
        nameArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"output.name"];
        php = [nameArray valueForKey:@"php"];


    }
    [_tabledata reloadData];
```

Tableview delegates:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [php count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"table" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.iteam.text=[php objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: I think this is because your `nameArray` var is `nil` since you don't have any path in your json that is `output.name` and also your `php` var will be nil too.

Comment: ya i had error like thread@sandeeptomar

Comment: its showing in nslog name array value came and php also came @tx2

Comment: `NSLog` the `php` you will get idea

Comment: nslog  the php 2 values came others are null because they are android @PayalManiyar

Comment: and your json is like that: `{"output": "name": [...], "php":[...]}`?

Comment: ya i saved php and android in different array so in can get separate value for php and other value are null @tx2

Comment: so in your description the example json structure that you provide has nothing to do with this because it hasn't this format...

Comment: You should explain, what you are trying to accomplish. Your question is more than confusing.

Comment: my json pattern like(1) Output->name->php and(2)output->name->android . i created  array for php and successfully displayed in nslog but i can't pass this array into tableview thats my question @CouchDeveloper

Comment: Please _Edit_ your question in order to be more clear. Comments are not suitable for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below line of code. Hope it will help you:

```
if(data){
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];


    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    nameArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"output.name"];
    php = [[nameArray valueForKey:@"php"] mutableCopy];
 [php removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];


}
[_tabledata reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an odd question, but here's some pointers.

First, you don't mention what that `php` variable is, but I assume it's an `NSArray`.  Before sending it to the `UITableView`, it might be worth checking how many elements you're *expecting* to show:

```
php = [nameArray valueForKey:@"php"];
NSLog(@"There are %d items to be displayed", (int)php.count);
```

Next, I had an issue a few years ago where my `UITableView` wasn't triggering my various UITableView delegate functions.

[Have a read of this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27189331/391605) to see what I needed to do, and try adding some breakpoints on your delegate functions to see if they *are* being called.

And finally, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function seems to create a new `TableViewCell` item *every time:*

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"table" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.iteam.text=[php objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

There should be some code in there to only create a new cell if the OS can't reuse an existing object:

```
TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"table" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = TableViewCell *cell=[[CompanyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"table"];
}
```

I would also be tempted to slip in a line OF code, to set the *default* textLabel, and see if anything appears:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [php objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Hope some of this helps...

Update

Actually, I reckon you're misinterpreting your JSON string.

Your JSON contains one element, `output`, which is an array of records.

So (I haven't tried this) I reckon you should be defining `php` like this:

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];
    php = [json valueForKey:@"output"];
```

That *should* give you the array for your `UITableView` to work with.  But from there, you'll need to access the relevant elements *within* each record.

```
{
    "id": {
            "php": "1"
    },
    "name": {
        "php": "ramkumar"
    },
    "image": {
        "1": "http:\/\/www.easyteach.gr\/users\/tutor\/1432636961.jpg"
    }
}
```

At the moment, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function would set the `text` to the *entire* record:

```
cell.iteam.text=[php objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```