# cellForItemAtIndexPath is not called for collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have taken `UICollectionView` in storyboard. I have set `datasource` and `delegate` also.
below method is called

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 return 4;
}
```

But `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not called.

Attaching screenshot of properties of `UICollectionView`. Any idea about this problem?[image: image 1]

[image]

Now collectionView is visible if I hide the navigationBar. In have set top constraint `Myheader Collection View.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom + 64` thought it is at top of controller. and I am receiving follwing warning after completion of method -`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

**Warning:** 
nable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fda80dcff20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fda830006f0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fda80daca10 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fda830006f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fda80efb580 )>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Comment: Is the `numberOfItemsInSection` called? How many `sections` did you specify?

Comment: I have specify 1 section.

Comment: what do you see after running the app ? one item or not even one ?

Comment: Try to increase the height of your collectionView. If it doesn't fit, it may not try to show an item (even if in theory the contentSize and the "visible" frame are different and shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: Try to set delegate and datasource programmatically on viewDidLoad

Comment: @KevinMac I have done it

Comment: if you dont even see one, i would suggest giving a background color to collectionview and running and see if that comes up with a color.  if it doesnt , i think its a autolayout issue

Comment: @Shubhank done that.collectionView is displaying but cell of collectionView is not displaying. `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not calling....

Comment: did you added the width constraint for collection view?

Comment: Your designed cell should be only one. Height/Width should be fixed at runtime and you have to return cell based on identifier.

Comment: @AshishKakkad `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is not calling...

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran nope

Comment: set width constraint and it will work.

Comment: Put your code so it is easy to find what is the issue, From which method you are trying to call collectionview reload method?

Comment: @KevinMac `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [myheaderCollectionView reloadData];
   
}`

Comment: @PayalManiyar Please share your project with scenario you are facing(Demo project). It may help to figure your problem out.

Comment: what is your item size @PayalManiyar

Comment: `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
CGSize size= CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/4, 34);
        NSLog(@"collection view : %@",collectionView);
        return size;
    }`

Comment: try to  add datasourse and delegate  to self manually also  in view did load

Comment: @KDeogharkar I have done that

Comment: @PayalManiyar try below answer

Comment: Try adding width constraint because cellForItemAtIndexPath will not called if the height and width constraints is not properly set.

Comment: **collection view : <UICollectionView: 0x7fe66b07da00; frame = (0 84; 320 258); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe66d0abce0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe66d082a50>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fe66d0b9c80>**
`contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 0}` problem is because of this.
but don't know the reason

Comment: @PayalManiyar In **Storyboard->XIB->Attributes Inspector** and then uncheck **Adjust Scroll View Insets**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[myCollectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Above line solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think you didn't set flow out correctly.

So, it will not go to `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method . so, set break point and check each and every flow layout method.

Sequence call of flow layout method ,

1 st in `viewdidload` customflowlayout will be called like , //if you have set

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    float ratio = self.aCollectionView.frame.size.width/3;
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(ratio, ratio)];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0];
```

2nd , in your case this method also called

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

3rd - you need to check from this line , // you have set it correctly or not

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    float width = collectionView.frame.size.width/3;//120
    float height = collectionView.frame.size.height/4;//120
    return CGSizeMake(width-17,height-14);
}
```

4th , this method called

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(14.0, 14.0, 0.0, 14.0);
}
```

and last here `cellforitem` method is called . so, your this method not called so, problem is in above method try to set break point and change cell size and edge insect and etc and then try,

5th , if all above set correct then , below method called.

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few years ago with my `UITableView`, and the solution was to drag'n'drop from my control to the parent view, in the Storyboard.

Just setting the values in my Objective-C code didn't seem to be enough...

[image]

Full details here:

[Setting DataSource and delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27189331/391605)