# UITableView sub class with predifined attributes

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass, xib, uistoryboard

I've built my own subclass which inherits form `UITableView`. I've implemented `iniWithFrame:` to set up some custom properties.

In interface builder I've set up a table view object to be a member of my custom class.

My problem is that `iniWithFrame:` is not being called and so I can't set up my properties and I'm not sure why it isn't called.

Comment: see this note about uitableview subclassing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144146/how-can-i-subclass-a-uitableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When created from an XIB / storyboard, `initWithFrame:` will not be called. Instead, the `initWithCoder:` method will be called because the instance is being unarchived.

In your subclass, you should implement both methods and apply your custom configuration in both cases.