# Subclassing and overridding UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code:

```
private var table = TableViewController();

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;

    table = TableViewController(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height));

}
```

I get an error saying no frame is overloaded? How do I fix this? TableViewController is a class I created. It inherits from UITableView.

Comment: May be this can help you, How to sublass UITableView
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144146/how-can-i-subclass-a-uitableview

Comment: need it in swift

Comment: What do you have in the `TableViewController` class ?

Comment: trying to create an init to handle this but failing at it

Comment: share your TableViewController code